# How to expand and collapse each list item using react?

Tags: css, reactjs

i want to display a list of items in the side panel. If the height of content in list item exceeds 36px i want to hide the contents fitting more than 36px and show expand button for that list item (whose content exceeded 36px) and clicking expand button should show the whole content of list item.

What i have tried so far?
I have added a ref to the span element containing the text that overflows. and expand button appears if height of span element exceeds 36px and clicking expand button shows the content for the list item.

The problem now?
It works fine. except that expand buttons are added at the end of all list items....i want them to be shown at the bottom of that particular list item whose content exceeds 36px.

It works like in image below.

[image: example image]

Below is the code,

```
switch (notification.type) {
    case 'new_model_uploaded':
        return (
            <Notification
                icon={<SvgProject width="26" height="26"/>}
                text={<Text
                    base_height={36}
                    name={name}
                    text=' created'
                    item_name={itemname}/>}
                timestamp={notification.timestamp}>
                <div className="additional_details">
                    <Image
                        width={70}
                        height={70}
                        item_id={filtered_item.id}
                    />
                </div>
            </Notification>
        );
    case 'deleted':
        return (
            <List
                icon={<Svg width="20" height="22"/>}
                text={<Text
                    base_height={36}
                    name={list.name}
                    text=' deleted item '
                    item_name={itemname}/>}
                    timestamp={item.timestamp}/>
        );
    default:
        return null;
}

function List(props) {
    return (
        <li className="list">
            <div className="details_container">
                <div className="details">
                    {props.icon}
                    {props.text}
                    <Time>{props.timestamp}</Time>
                </div>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </li>
    );
}

class Text extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.span_ref = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            expanded: false,
            overflow: false,
        };
     }

     componentDidMount () {
         if (this.span_ref.current.offsetHeight < 
         this.span_ref.current.scrollHeight) {
             this.setState({overflow: true});
         }
     }

     set_expanded = () => {
          this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded});
     };

     render () {
         return (
             <span ref={this.span_ref} className={this.props.classname} 
                 style={{overflow: 'hidden', height: (this.state.expanded ? 
                 null : this.props.base_height)}}>
                 <span className="red">{name}</span> {this.props.text} 
                     <span className="red">{this.props.name} 
                         {this.props.item_name}</span>
                         {this.props.additional_text}

                {this.state.overflow && <button onClick={this.set_expanded} 
                    style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 
                    0}}>expand</button>}
           </span> 
       );
    }
}

.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px;
    min-height: 49px;

    li {
        list-style: none;
    }

   .details_container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin-right: 8px;

       .details {
            display: flex;
            color: #333;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-grow: 1;

            svg {
                margin-right: 8px;
                margin-left: 7px;
                flex: 0 0 auto;
                align-self: center;
                flex-shrink: 0;
            }

            span {
                flex-grow: 1;
            }


            time {
                flex: 0 0 auto;
                margin-left: 8px;
                padding-top: 2px;
                color: #CCCCCC;
            }
        } 

        span {
            word-break: break-all;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is not complete though, but can you try putting position: relative for the outermost span in the Text component so that the button is positioned relative to that span?

Comment: thanks added a container for span element and added ref to it.